# Doctrine won't pull a date time filed using ->select

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a legacy symphony project (v2.1) and I'm trying to use doctrine to pull up a date time field using the select statement (SessionDesign.created). However when I check the results it only pulls up null values.

The logs say it can't be converted to string, which is fine and all, but how to get the select statement to pull up created as a string?

The code:

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('fos_user.email, fos_user.fcid, SessionDesign.sessionID,      SessionDesign.created')
     ->from('FYPEmailsBundle:User', 'fos_user')
     ->join('fos_user.SessionDesign', 'SessionDesign')
     ->where('fos_user.emailok = true')
     ->getQuery();
      $result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine is able to auto-convert date fields to `\DateTime` only if  the field is mapped as date/time field. Make sure your `SessionDesign.created` field is correctly mapped to "datetime" type. [Here's the list of supported doctrine mapping types](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types).

Whether you use annotations

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;
```

or yaml

```
SessionDesign:
  fields:
    created:
      type: datetime
```

If it is set up correctly, doctrine **should return `created` as \DateTime object** in your array result, not a string. Just make a `var_dump` on `$result` right after `$result = $query->getArrayResult();` to be sure.

Comment: The Entity is set as but it still gives me the error. On the server side i get: "Unable to convert object of date time to string"

/**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     
     */
    private $created;

Comment: Is the stacktrace point you directly to `getArrayResult` line? What's the doctrine2 version you use? Because it does not look right, I tested the code in the answer and it works fine with doctrine 2.5.

Comment: The version is 2.1.6. The stack stack trace in the error logs for the SQL.